# what's the difference between "hold off" vs "hold off on"?

Tags: verbs

what's the difference between hold off and hold off on?

I hold off the decision.
I hold off on the decision.

Thank you

Comment: To me, *hold off* without the *on* makes me think of *fend off*. As if you are keeping the attacking decision at bay (with a chair or something)—rather than just postponing it. But that may be too subjective an interpretation, so I don't want to provide it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to English stackexchange.

Both are acceptable and can be used, it comes down to personal preference.

'Hold off' is a transitive verb, whereas 'hold off on' is an idiom.

I personally prefer the structure of the idiom, 'hold off on the decision' as I feel it is less ambiguous.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20off

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20off%20on